# how to make this program efficient in c?

Tags: c

here is the code

```
void main()
{
    int x,y,i=0,o,p;


    printf("enter the command");
    scanf("%s",dir);
    printf("enter the limit");
    scanf("%d%d",&o,&p);
    printf("enter the place");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    clrscr();
    if(((x>0)&&(x<o))&&((y>0)&&(y<p)))
    {
        while(dir[i]!='\0')
        {
            for(i=0;i<strlen(dir);i++)
            {
                if(dir[i]=='l')
                {
                    if(a=='n')
                    a='w';
                    else if(a=='w')
                    a='s';
                    else if(a=='s')
                    a='e';
                    else
                    a='n';
                }
                else if(dir[i]=='r')
                {
                    if(a=='n')
                    a='e';
                    else if(a=='e')
                    a='s';
                    else if(a=='s')
                    a='w';
                    else
                    a='n';
                }

            }
        }
        printf("%d %d %c",x,y,a);
    }
    else printf("out of area");
    getch();
}
```

how to make the above program efficient using some oops concept in c or by some way?

Comment: try adding some indentation, that should speed up the reading of the program consideraby :-)

Comment: @fvu how to add indentation? what is indentation actually means?

Comment: Just by removing calls to `clrscr` and `getch`, and getting input from the command-line you can get an improvement of efficiency of approximately 86474266.3%

Comment: @pmg not getting u clearly. removing clrscr and getch. then how would i get my screen clear for next run and how to view the output without getch func...

Comment: @tks C isn't an OO language, so you'll need to move to C++ to improve this using OO concepts.

Comment: what is indentation how to implement that?

Comment: Indentation is what Cris Gregg edited your question to add.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Paul In principle, I would agree with you, but...

Comment: @tks: C isn't really suited for user interface stuff. It shines when used to **do** stuff, not waiting around for the user to type things: use a scripting language for that and integrate the scripting language with the C functions

Comment: @tks: Why do you feel it isn't efficient? Which part of it feels slow to you? As the saying goes, *premature optimisation is the root of all evil*.

Comment: @pmg, tks: No offense OP, but you should probably try to get some basic concepts straightened out before you try to "integrate a scripting language with C".

Comment: `clrscr` nor 'getch' is not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to improve the program stepwise, and as it's written in C making it OOPSy is probably not the highest priority.  Eg start out by improving the selection logic by introducing a `switch()` statement:

```
switch (dir[i]) {
    case 'l':
        ...
        break;
    case 'r':
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ....
        break;
}
```

You can also replace the inner if-chain with a switch, but that would get pretty messy. So, break that inner construction out in a function.

```
char newa (char olda) {
    if(olda=='n') return 'w';
    if(olda=='w') return 's';
    if(olda=='s') return 'e';
    return 'n';
}
```

See?  Easier on the eye even with plain if's :-)
That way the inner block becomes

```
a = newa(a);
```

Bonus points if you figure out how to fold the 3 very similar but not entirely identical inner blocks into 1 function!

And so on.  Just keep on improving step-wise, making your program more readable at every iteration.

Ah yes, and while you're at it, put some useful comments here and there, especially comments that will help you figure out in 3 months what the &!@%#& you tried to achieve with a certain function :-)

Edit: according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation) indentation is

> The placement of text farther to the
>   right to separate it from surrounding
>   text.

And I'm incredibly puzzled that this concept seems foreign to you.

Comment: ya great thanks. sure i will see that indentation here after in every program. thanks for ur great answer. any other changes other than u mentioned above?

Comment: @tks glad to be of assistance, please consider accepting the answer if you feel it helped you.  Sure, there may be more possible and useful iterations, but a major part of programming work is to see and implement these during the project - as soon as you implement refactorings others will become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

One that's small enough that it's often easy to miss is:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(dir);i++)
```

The compiler doesn't (at least normally) have any way of knowing that `strlen` will return the same result from every call, so it'll end up being called on every iteration of the loop. To prevent that, you want to do something like:

```
size_t len = strlen(dir);
for (i=0; i<len; i++) /* ... */
```

You're currently doing the conversion of (apparently) directions using cascaded `if` statements. I'd probably build a small table, and just do a table lookup:

```
char results[2]['z'-'a'];

results[0]['n'-'a'] = 'w';
results[0]['w'-'a'] = 's';
results[0]['s'-'a'] = 'e';
results[0]['e'-'a'] = 'n';
results[1]['n'-'a'] = 'e';
results[1]['e'-'a'] = 's';
results[1]['s'-'a'] = 'w';
results[1]['w'-'a'] = 'n';

a = results[dir[i]=='r'][a-'a'];
```

Comment: `'z'-'a'` is 25, but `'w'` is 119 in ascii code.

Comment: Oops. Quite right (or mostly, anyway -- 'z'-'a' won't be 25 on EBCDIC, but your basic point stands anyway). Fixed.